# Iterate through all possible values in array which give 1 in sum

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, math

I have an array of 4 values. For example: `[0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.3]` (sum of elements = 1)
How to iterate though all possible values with increment 0.1 to get in sum 1.

example:

```
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0,0]
[0.9, 0.1, 0.0, 0,0]
[0.9, 0.0, 0.1, 0,0]
......
[0.7, 0.2, 0.0, 0,1]
```

Preferably in python or java. Or just algorithm explanation in pseudocode

Comment: this is the [coin problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) with coin values 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, ..., 0.9, 1.0.

Comment: You can phrase this as finding integer partitions of 10 (then divide the values in each partition by 10 to get 0.1, 0.2, etc). A web search for "integer partitions" should turn up a lot of hits.

Comment: This is not the coin problem (as linked).  It's also simpler than integer partitions, since we aren't looking for sorted permutations.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically an integer problem couched as a
floating point problem. It can be solved as a
FP problem, but the inexactness of `float` representations
and the inability of Python builtins like `range` to
provide floating point ranges makes it more difficult.
So easier to solve it in the neat, exact integer realm
then display the results as floating point values.

It's possible to generate all possible combinations of
values, then test whether they sum to the target value.
That's what some of the other proposed solutions do.
But that's a little brute-force. It's also possible to
generate *only* those vectors/lists that sum to the
target value. This solution does so with recursive
generators.

```
def vectors(length, target):
    """
    Generate all lists of whole numbers of given
    length that add up to the target value.
    """
    if length == 1:
        yield [target]
    else:
        for firstval in range(target+1):
            for rest in vectors(length-1, target-firstval):
                yield [firstval] + rest

TARGET=10
LENGTH=4
for vec in vectors(LENGTH, TARGET):
    print [ v / float(TARGET) for v in vec ]
```

This yields:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.9]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.8]
...
[0.9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1]
[0.9, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0]
[0.9, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0]
[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at **itertools.permutations**:

> ```
> import itertools
> allPermutations = itertools.permutations([0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0]*4, 4)
> Sum1Permutations = [x for x in allPermutations if sum(x) == 1]
> ```

As @HuStmpHrrr points out this is using brute force to solve the problem. The algorithm for generating all the permutations which add to 1.0 is this one:

> ```
> Sum1Permutations = []
> for x in range(10):
>     for y in range(10-x+1):
>         for z in range(10-x-y+1):
>             Sum1Permutations.append([float(x)/10, float(y)/10, float(z)/10, float(10 - x - y - z)/10])
> ```

Or, using a list comprehension:

> ```
> Sum1Permutations = [[float(x)/10,float(y)/10,float(z)/10,float(10-x-y-z)/10] for x in range(10) for y in range(10-x+1) for z in range(10-x-y+1)]
> ```

Comment: this is not smart. it's brute force search.

Comment: the list comprehension misses many permutations, for example [0.8, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0]

Comment: Correct, there was a problem with the boundaries. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the dollowing list comprehension:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> s = [list(p/10. for p in prd) 
         for prd in product(range(11), repeat=4) if sum(prd) == 10]
>>> len(s)
286
>>> [0.,1.,0.,0.] in s
True
>>> [.8,.2,.0,.0] in s
True
>>>
```

It is **itertools.product** that is needed here.

Comment: This is still brute force.  A pythonic brute force, but still.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the values, pretend you're placing four subintervals into an interval of length 1.  Then the four values are determined precisely by the three endpoints of those subintervals.

```python
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as cwr

for (one,onetwo,onetwothree) in cwr(range(11),3):
    print([one/10,(onetwo-one)/10,(onetwothree-onetwo)/10,(10-onetwothree)/10])
```